# Why does the unbiased statistic in this example be MVUE immediately?

Tags: exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, parameter-estimation, sufficient-statistics

I am reading "[Introduction to Mathematical Statistics](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/_/V1SzswEACAAJ?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtxqiZsJH4AhVp-jgGHY5XCwgQ7_IDegQIERAE)" to familiarize myself with sufficient statistics. I got stuck by an example in Sec. 7.3 of the book. Below are page 427 and 428 that relate to my question.

[image]

My question is the last sentence of Example 7.3.1 underlined in red in the screenshot. The preceding steps of the solution find an unbiased statistic $[(n-1)Y_2]/n$ of $\theta$; let's denote it as $Y_3$. In my understanding, next we need to follow Theorem 7.3.1 in page 427 to construct an unbiased estimator $E(Y_3|Y_1)\buildrel \Delta \over =\varphi(Y_1)$. But:

1. The example does not make any attempt to compute $E(Y_3|Y_1)$,
2. The theorem requires that the unbiased estimator (here $Y_3$) be "not a function of $Y_1$ alone." But $Y_3$ is a function of sufficient statistic $Y_1$. How to reconcile this violation?
3. Even if we compute $E(Y_3|Y_1)$ according to Theorem 7.3.1, we only have that its variance is less than or equal to that of $Y_3$. We don't have, however, that this variance is less than or equal to that of any other statistics, which is the definition of MVUE (minimum-variance unbiased estimator). So, why does the last sentence claim immediately that the unbiased statistic $Y_3$ "is an MVUE of $\theta$"?

I tried my best to read the text to fill the gap but failed, so I ask for help here for a reason for such an immediate conclusion. If you know of this text, you can infer from the fact that I read this book that I am not a major in math and my knowledge of probability and statistics is at naïve level, so please provide an accessible answer to my questions. Thank you.